# Linear trasformation Proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that, for a linear transformation, it is worth that:

$f(a\bar{x}+b\bar{y})=af(\bar{x})+bf(\bar{y})$

Until now, I have proved that

$f(\bar{x}+\bar{y})=f(\bar{x})+f(\bar{y})$.

How can I use this result in order to prove that
$f(a\bar{v}) = af(\bar{v})$ 
for every $a\in \mathbb{R} $ ?

Comment: Maybe apply it with $x=v, \, y=0$.

Comment: What definition of "linear transformation" are you using for this question?

Comment: I'm trying to derive the definition of linear trasformation (the formal one), starting only with $f(\bar{x}+\bar{y})=f(\bar{x})+f(\bar{y})$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact thar $f(a\bar{v})=af(\bar{v})$ for arbitrary $a$ is infact part of the defenition of linear operators. Nevertheless, for integer values of $a$ we have
$$f(a\bar{v}) = f(\sum\bar{v})\text{(Sum it $a$ times)}$$
$$=\sum f(\bar{v})$$
$$=af(\bar{v})$$

Comment: Nice, How can derive it for real values ?

Comment: @Qwerto All additive functions need not be linear (http://planetmath.org/thereexistadditivefunctionswhicharenotlinear ). So you cannot deduce the homegenity property just from the additive property

Comment: Can we only derive for integer values of $a$  or also for rational values of $a$  ?

Comment: @Qwerto this can only be true for only integer $a$, but needn’t always hold true for rational $a$ (refer the counter example in above comment). This is why it is put as a separate condition in the definition

Comment: A book i'm reading says that it's possible to derive $f(a\bar{v}) = af(\bar{v})$ knowing that $f(\bar{x}+\bar{y})=f(\bar{x})+f(\bar{y})$ . But it doesnt prove it, so i'm trying to understand how it's possible...

Comment: @Qwerto What book says that proof possible?